# Gatsby - Cannot read property 'component---src-pages-index-jsx' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, browser, gatsby

I am trying to migrate my existing ReactJS app with WordPress backend to GatsbyJS. I am new to GatsbyJS and followed the instructions on their page for the setup on a Windows 10 machine. The setup ran pretty well and I could start my migration process, but after some time I only got the following error when trying to load the page:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'component---src-pages-index-jsx' of undefined

fetchResource
D:/GitHub/gatsby-starter-wordpress/.cache/loader.js:77
  74 | // Find resource
  75 | let resourceFunction
  76 | if (resourceName.slice(0, 12) === `component---`) {
> 77 |   resourceFunction = asyncRequires.components[resourceName]
  78 | } else if (resourceName.slice(0, 9) === `layout---`) {
  79 |   resourceFunction = asyncRequires.layouts[resourceName]
  80 | } else {
View compiled
getResourceModule
D:/GitHub/gatsby-starter-wordpress/.cache/loader.js:112
  109 |     cb(failedResources[resourceName])
  110 |   })
  111 | } else {
> 112 |   fetchResource(resourceName, (err, executeChunk) => {
  113 |     if (err) {
  114 |       cb(err)
  115 |     } else {
View compiled
getResourcesForPathname
D:/GitHub/gatsby-starter-wordpress/.cache/loader.js:358
  355 |     })
  356 |   }
  357 | }
> 358 | getResourceModule(page.componentChunkName, (err, c) => {
  359 |   if (err) {
  360 |     handleResourceLoadError(
  361 |       page.path,
View compiled
new ComponentRenderer
D:/GitHub/gatsby-starter-wordpress/.cache/component-renderer.js:26
  23 | 
  24 |   this.state = {
  25 |     location,
> 26 |     pageResources: loader.getResourcesForPathname(location.pathname),
  27 |   }
  28 | }
  29 | 
View compiled
▶ 43 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
D:/GitHub/gatsby-starter-wordpress/.cache/app.js:42
  39 |   Root = Root.default
  40 | }
  41 | 
> 42 | domReady(() =>
  43 |   ReactDOM.render(
  44 |     <HotContainer>
  45 |       <Root />
View compiled
HTMLDocument.listener
D:/GitHub/gatsby-starter-wordpress/node_modules/domready/ready.js:23
```

I tried removing any of my custom written components until I ended up with the normal starting boilerplate. But it still wouldn't work. So I went on and even created a new project to test if `gatsby-cli` is still functional. But uninstalling and reinstalling the package did still not fix my problem. Any help or tip would be appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, this looks like it might be resolved by removing your `.cache` folder (`rm -rf .cache` on *nix…not sure what the Windows equivalent is) and re-running `gatsby develop`.

Comment: @coreyward I am not sure if it was your solution but it seems to work now. I additionally installed a Linux subsystem for Windows in the belief that it could somehow work. and no it does so thank you i guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. I've fixed it by **cleaning the browser cache**.
I've done `gatsby clean` before cleaning the chrome's cache but I think is not related.

Comment: Cleaning the browser cache (hard refresh with cmd + shift + R on macOS in Chrome) did it for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

had this issue with `gatsby-plugin-offline` plugin, cleaning the cache didn't help so I disabled the plugin for the `development` (local) environment, it works well on production